# After converting .shp to .gpx, there seems to be no content in the .gpx

Tags: qgis, convert, gpx

I tried to convert .shp files into .gpx using QGIS. Originally, the .shp were in the Swiss Coordinates (CH190) but I've changed them into WGS.

I can load the .gpx into QGIS which works really fine. Trying to load it into Movescount / Google Earth / GPStracks.com, it fails.

I tried to with

```
GPS_use_extensions YES and NO.
```

I checked

```
skip attribute creation
```

and I tried

```
FORCE_GPX_TRACK YES and NO.
```

Any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error when it fails?

Comment: A small data sample would be nice.

Comment: what type of shape file would you like to convert to gpx, point, polyline, polygon?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to bad data.

A GPX file is a simple text file that can be opened in notepad and is formatted as XML.

- Try opening the file in notepad to double check any malformed/unclosed tags.
- Try comparing the  and  headers with another file that does load to locate a bad heading.
- Try deleting all but one or two  ...  sections and see if the data loads.